# How to show nested JSON data in table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have JSON like this

```
    {   "StartElement": {
        "Count": "14",
        "Notification": [
          {
            "contact": null,
            "Date": "20 June 2016",
            "Message": null,
            "Viewed": "1"
          },
          {
            "contact": "99230332210",
            "Date": "20 June 2016",
            "Message": "I need help",
            "Viewed": "1"
          }
     }
```

and my JSON parsing in `viewDidLoad` is this:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someURL.com/JSONToFetch?"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
            NSLog(@"code: %d",[(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode]);

        }] resume];
```

Now, i want to show `"Message"` content into table view cells. How to store this data into array so i can load it into `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Thanx for help :)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/ read first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get value for a particular key then you have to convert response in dictionary format and after conversion you can get value of particular key

Please convert your response like this

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someURL.com/JSONToFetch?"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];



   NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
            [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
   NSError *error;
   NSDictionary  *requestReply=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];//use Reading option NSJSONReadingAllowFragments because response contain array
                NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
                NSLog(@"code: %d",[(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode]);


NSArray *notification_list=[[requestReply valueForKey:@"StartElement"] valueForKey:@"Notification"];

            }] resume];
```

Comment: I tried this but `notification_list` is still null, can u plz help me getting all `"Message"` into an array

Comment: your json is not valid it does not contain closing array

Comment: {   "StartElement": {
        "Count": "14",
        "Notification": [
          {
            "contact": null,
            "Date": "20 June 2016",
            "Message": null,
            "Viewed": "1"
          },
          {
            "contact": "99230332210",
            "Date": "20 June 2016",
            "Message": "I need help",
            "Viewed": "1"
          }
   ]
}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can save your response in a dictionary

```
 NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

From this dictionary you can extract your messages into NSarray and use it into your table

Comment: Yes i used this, Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your JSON parsing is wrong, you should parsing your JSON to a NSDictionary, and Notification to a NSArray。I recommend you to use a third party JSON parse library